# How to notify if a class property of a class property has changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, oop, events

Let's say I have two classes in my WPF application:

```
public class Radio
{
    public int Volume { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle
{
    public Radio MusicRadio { get; set; }

    private void Explode()
    {
        if (MusicRadio.Volume == 10)
        {
           Application.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

...where `Vehicle` has a property which is an instance of the `Radio` class. In my code behind, I want to set the volume of that radio class when a button is clicked:

```
private void startButton_Click(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Vehicle Xterra = new Vehicle() { MusicRadio = new Radio() };

    for (int i = 0; i < 666; i++)
    {
        Xterra.MusicRadio.Volume = i;
    }
}
```

In the above code, the application should shutdown via the `Explode()` method once the for loop reaches 10 iterations.

I want my `Vehicle` class to execute its private function `Explode()` every time the volume the `MusicRadio` property changes. How can I make sure it is alerted to this change?

Comment: In Java or C#? Code looks like C#... What is the GUI? Winforms? HTML/ ASP/ MVC?

Comment: @AustinFrench Sorry, I updated to fix syntax and be more clear. It is C# and WPF.

Comment: Please fix your post so that the narrative matches the code. You write things like _"`Radio` is a member of the class `Vehicle`"_ and _"`Xterra` class to execute its private function `Explode()`"_, but in the code you posted, `Radio` is a standalone class, not a member of `Vehicle`, and the `Explode()` method is a member of `Vehicle`, not of `Xterra`. `Xterra` isn't even a class in the code above.

Comment: That said, if you are using WPF, you certainly should be familiar with `INotifyPropertyChanged`, which seems like it might be applicable here. Or just write an explicit setter for the `MusicRadio` property, in which you call `Explode()`. Please improve the question so a good answer may be provided.

Comment: Do you have complete control of both the radio and the vehicle class?

Comment: @Dave yes, they are classes I have defined.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to add a `VolumeChanged` event to your `Radio` class. Then in your `Vehicle` class, you can subscribe to the event and call `Explode` from there. **Note** I haven't worked with wpf, I am just assuming it will work there. Happy to delete the answer if that's not the case.

First, add the event to the Radio class:

```
public class Radio
{
    private int volume;

    public int Volume
    {
        get { return volume; }
        set
        {
            if (value == volume) return;
            volume = value;
            OnVolumeChanged(new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler VolumeChanged;

    protected virtual void OnVolumeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        VolumeChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

Then, subscribe to it in the Vehicle class, and call `Explode` from there (or move the `Explode` code into the event directly):

```
public class Vehicle
{
    private Radio musicRadio;

    public Radio MusicRadio
    {
        get { return musicRadio; }
        set
        {
            musicRadio = value;
            if (musicRadio != null)
            {
                // In the unlikely event that the same radio is assigned more than once, 
                // we only want to subscribe to the event one time, so remove it first.
                musicRadio.VolumeChanged -= MusicRadio_VolumeChanged;
                musicRadio.VolumeChanged += MusicRadio_VolumeChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    private void MusicRadio_VolumeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Explode();
    }

    private void Explode()
    {
        if (MusicRadio.Volume == 10)
        {
            Application.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

WPF MVC

ViewModel:

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyDataErrorInfo
    {
        public void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property.GetMemberInfo().Name));
            }
        }
}


public class TankModel : ObservableObject
{
  public float Level
        {
            get { return level; }
            set
            {
                try
                {
                    if (level != value)
                    {
                        level = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged(() => Level);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.Error(ex);
                }
            }
        }
}
```